# Limit the number of retries in RabbitMQ queue head when defaultRequeRejected is set to true

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a application where messages are consumed by a multi node Listeners. The issue i am running into is i have to limit the number of retries which are performed by RabbitMQ once the consumer is unable to process any of the messages. I found out there is way to dead letter this message to a DLQ and setting up a TTL for the failed message while deadlettering it and once TTL is up it can fetched back to consumer/worker  queue by having consumer/worker queue as DLQ in the original dead letter queue. However the issue is want to maintain the order in which events are processed as sequence of events is an important aspect. If i dead letter a message and have it delayed retry the sequence of events would mismatch and hence causing issues of data corruption.

For Example: There is message for create order and then there is another message for updating the order. Now while processing the create order message it somehow got failed and is sent to DLQ and the next message of update order is processed, The update order event will fail because it will not be able to find the actual order.

So what we need here is if a message fails to process at consumer it should be tried at the head of queue until "n" number of times by rabbitmq and if it still fails then we open a circuit breaker which will stop the further events to be pushed to queue until this failing message gets processed or is discarded as per policy of TTL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance